# pyspark ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

I'm working with 2 rather large rdds: a list of latitudes `lat` and a list of longitudes `long`. I'm trying to use `latlong = lat.zip(long)` to mash them together, but when I try to look at it, I get the ValueError:

```
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.next(InterruptibleIterator.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1699)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:239)
```

In the end I tried other simple commands too, like `lat.count()` returns the same error.

What does this mean? I'm not converting any strings into floats?

EDIT: Getting Lat Long rdds:
I have a taxi dataset with pickup latitude and longitude, and a ZipCode dataset. I have an equation that I'm trying to use to find the nearest zip code.

```
pickuplat = taxirdd.map(lambda p: float(p[2])) #taxi pickup lat
zclat = zc.map(lambda p: (p[3]) ) #zip code center lat
alllat = pickuplat.cartesian(zclat) #compare taxi_lat with each zip_lat
lat = alllat.map(lambda x: x[0], x[1], x[0] - x[1]) #lat is actually the DIFFERENCE between 2 latitudes, my bad!!

pickuplong = taxirdd.map(lambda p: float(p[3]) ) #same with long
zclong = zc.map(lambda p: (p[4]) )
alllong = pickuplong.cartesian(zclong)
long = alllong.map(lambda x: x[0], x[1], x[0] - x[1]) #get pickuplong, zclong, and the diff.
```

Now I want to zip lat and long together because I need to use both of them together in my next equation, and I can't use 2 RDDs in a function.

*After some more testing, I am able to use all these functions on the taxirdd before I convert the values to floats, but then trying `pickuplat.count()` yields that the ValueError. I tried converting the results back into unicode like it was in the original taxirdd and tried again, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Sometimes rdd imports as Unicode string. This is a large string of many entries or a line on a text file. May need to convert to string() then start processing to get it to look like you want.

Comment: I was successfully able to do math on each column, so I don't think that's it. But I tried to save each rdd as a text file to convert it to string, anyway, and I get the same error. Is there another way to convert the rdd back to string?

Comment: Could you provide the code you use to create `lat` and `long`?

Comment: I've included it under EDIT